# Pool with generator: Chunkify

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I'm using `pathos.Pool`, but I suppose the technique required is comparable to those from `multiprocessing.Pool.

I have a generator that yields a large (huge) list of things to do.

```
from pathos import ProcessingPool
def doStuff(item):
    return 1

pool = ProcessingPool(nodes=32)
values = pool.map(doStuff, myGenerator)
```

Unfortunately, the function to apply to my generated items (here: `doStuff`) clears very quickly. Therefore, so far I have been unable to generate a speed boost from serializing this - in fact, the multiprocessing version of the code runs slower than the original.

I assume this is because the overhead of delivering the next item from the pool to the workers is large compared to the time it takes the worker to complete the task.

I suppose the solution would be to "chunkify" the generated items: Group the items into `n`  lists and then provide them to a pool with `n` many workers (since all of the jobs should take almost exactly long). Or perhaps a less extreme version.

What would be a good way of achieving this in Python?

Comment: Why not trying something like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) instead of Multiprocessing. Do not forget the overhead of context switching.